# how to get oldest and newest in hive

Tags: hive, hql

I have a table named signal with the following columns

1. entity_id
2. item_id
3. month_id
4. signal_count

input table :

```
| entity_id | item_id | month_id | signal_count |

     101         3        2015           2
     104         4        2017           1
     101         1        2017           1
     104         2        2016           0
     107         2        2011           1
     107         0        2011           2
```

I need the sum of signal_count and item_id as oldest_item_id and newest_item_id based on month_id and group by entity_id

and month_id is same then take the least value of item_id

The expected result would be as follows:

```
| entity_id | oldest_item_id | newest_month_id | signal_count |

     101             3                1               3 
     104             2                4               1
     107             0                0               3
```

Comment: please add some sample data and the expected result to the question. also you need to define the logic to get *first row* in each group.

Comment: can you see now

Comment: suppose month_id is same then how to take the least value of item_id

Answer (score 1):

Use `sum` window function to get the sum per entity_id and `first_value` to get the oldest and newest item_id based on the desired ordering of month_id.

```
select distinct entity_id,oldest_item_id,newest_item_id,signal_count_sum
from (select t.*
            ,sum(signal_count) over(partition by entity_id) as signal_sum
            ,first_value(item_id) over(partition by entity_id order by month_id) as oldest_item_id
            ,first_value(item_id) over(partition by entity_id order by month_id desc) as newest_item_id          
      from tbl t
     ) t
```

To break ties and get least item_id in case there are multiple rows with the same month_id per entity_id add `item_id` to `order by` with a `rows` specification.

```
select distinct entity_id,oldest_item_id,newest_item_id,signal_count_sum
from (select t.*
            ,sum(signal_count) over(partition by entity_id) as signal_sum
            ,first_value(item_id) over(partition by entity_id order by month_id,item_id rows unbounded preceding) as oldest_item_id
            ,first_value(item_id) over(partition by entity_id order by month_id desc,item_id rows unbounded preceding) as newest_item_id          
      from tbl t
     ) t
```